# Is it possible to "freeze" a WordPress blog?

Tags: plugins, images, export

I'm currently running a 365 photos project and it's based on a WordPress platform. Currently this is very helpful because I can upload the photos easily and manage comments and stuff.

Because we are reaching the end of the year, I would like to "freeze" the blog. I mean, remove all the WordPress engine code and leave all the pages as statics HTML. This will allow me not to have to get updates for WordPress, or worry about security.

**Is there any way to "freeze" a WordPress blog?** Do I have to download the entire site with, say, [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) and re-upload it or is there a fancier way to do this?

BTW, I have no interest of keeping the comments on or any interactivity that the blog has. I just want a static website.

Comment: Downloading the site with HTTrack and reuploading works rather well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this Wordpress plugin [WP Static HTML output](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/)

> This plugin produces a static HTML version of your wordpress install,
>   incredibly useful for anyone who would like the publishing power of
>   wordpress but whose webhost doesn't allow dynamic PHP driven sites -
>   such as MobileMe. You can run your development site on a different
>   domain or offline, and the plugin will change all relevant URLs when
>   you publish your site. It's a simple but powerful plugin, and after
>   hitting the publish button, the plugin will output a ZIP file of your
>   entire site, ready to upload straight to it's new home.

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score -3):

The best way to do that would be to completely delete the wp-admin folder. The site will still function as it does now, but won't be accessible through the web. This would also allow you to simply upload the wp-admin folder if you ever wanted to make some changes.

Comment: And how does this solution solves the _remove all the WordPress engine code and leave all the pages as statics HTML_ problem?